# How to give a host name to magento 2 project

Tags: magento2

I need to do what is asked here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9682262/how-do-i-connect-to-this-localhost-from-another-computer-on-the-same-network 
on my magento 2 project, but when I apply the first 2 steps and use the hostname I configured the result is as in the picture below .. and the page title is 404 not found[image]

that's what I've added to vhost file in c:\xampp\apache\conf\extra :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   DocumentRoot "/xampp/htdocs/yourParts"
   ServerName yourparts.local
</VirtualHost>
```

and that's in host file c:\Windows\system32\drivers\etc :

```
##
# Host Database
# localhost is used to configure the loopback interface
##
#...
127.0.0.1 yourparts.local
```

Comment: after adding virtual hosts you've to restart apache from xampp. then use yourparts.local not 127.0.0.1,also can you please add screenshot for the network tab in browser. need to check why resources not loading. also make sure you deploy statics

Comment: I've already deploy statics and restarted apache 
here is network tab https://ibb.co/ime8AL

Comment: the screen for console not the network. can you please provide something like https://ibb.co/dAv9H0 to show the url

Comment: https://ibb.co/idBYc0

Comment: I don't know why URL changes to 127.0.0.1/yourParts when I write yourparts.local

Comment: in the db `core_config_data` table change `web/unsecure/base_url` and `web/secure/base_url` to your new url

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86000/discussion-between-m-elwan-and-yomna-mansour).

Answer (score 0):

**/etc/httpd.conf** find this

```
# Virtual hosts
# Include etc/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

And change to this

```
# Virtual hosts
Include etc/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

Save and restart the server

Comment: I've found this file in c:\xampp\apache\conf\extra and that line is already uncommented, but I cannot find that file in etc